# Difficulties with Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, xna

I tried this tutorial: http://wellroundedgeek.com/post/2011/01/25/Simple-XNA-Cross-Platform-Settings-Manager.aspx
But I have difficulties to call the LoadSettings() method. I get this error message in Game1 Initialize: 'WindowsGame22.AppSettings' does not contain a definition for 'LoadSettings' and no extension method 'LoadSettings' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsGame22.AppSettings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
AppSettings Loading = new AppSettings();    
public Game1()
{
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
}  
protected override void Initialize()
{
        Loading = Loading.LoadSettings();
        base.Initialize();
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to that tutorial, the name of the class and method you should be calling is `SettingsManager.LoadSettings`.  `AppSettings` is a static member of the static `SettingsManager` class, but it doesn't contain the method you're attempting to call.

Comment: Thanks. I have another problem. The file "settings.xml" isn't getting saved. I tried it on Windows 7 but I couldn't find the file. Why isn't this working?

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
           KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                SettingsManager.Settings.HasRunOnce = false;
            if (SettingsManager.Settings.HasRunOnce == false)
                SettingsManager.SaveSettings();
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }